# My plant is sick, what can I do?

Tags: diseases

This plant used to be green, since a year ago it's mostly yellow (most but not all of the leave is yellow) and stopped growing - even shrinking a bit.

I suppose it has a disease. But I don't even know what the tree is, nor the disease. Is this a lost cause?

(note: I'm a total noob in gardening)

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a typical variegated euonymus, doesn't look like it has any problem. As I remember they could have both variegated and solid green branches on the same plant.

Comment: Definitely looks variegated (not diseased or something), but I do see some chlorosis on a couple leaves in the lower left corner. It's hard to say what that means (but it might need fertilizer).

Comment: But why does it not grow at all, I'm fairly positive it's even been slowly shrinking over the summer. Aren't plants supposed to grow rather than shrink lol, I don't know really as I said I'm a complete noob. Also the plant looked a lot greener years ago and now it looks more yellow, although I can't be 100% positive on that.

Comment: Generally , woody plants grow in the spring  and do not get new growth in the summer.

Comment: OK one last thing: I want it to grow upwards to create privacy. Is there anything I can do to help?

Comment: You can selectively prune most plants for a preferred shape . You will have some risk of lower parts getting sparse if you prune them.  I think euonymus may come in upright and lower, spreading varieties, but that would mean panting more shrubs.